# Cant connect to postgres docker container in docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, docker-compose

I'm using the following files:

1. [wait-for.sh:](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for)
2. Dockerfile:

   ```
   FROM ubuntu:16.04
   COPY ./wait-for.sh /home/
   RUN chmod +x /home/wait-for.sh
   CMD /home/wait-for.sh db:5432 -t 30 -- echo working!!!
   ```
3. docker-compose.yml

   ```
   version: '3'
   services:
      tester:
         build:
           context: .
           dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
         depends_on:
            - db
        db:
           image: postgres:9.5
           expose:
             - "5432"
   ```

Problem is, the tester never manages to connect to the db (30 sec timeout and exit). Am I missing something?

Comment: what do the logs say?

Comment: Your yml file is invalid. This file is white space sensitive and your tester and db services are at different indentation levels.